# How to change the image to text for Treantjs collapsible tree view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, treeview

I have to draw a representation of data using collapsible tree structure, i am using below example link for my purpose :

http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/collapsable/

But the problem i am facing is the above link had images at every node, i want to replace it with text which when i am doing it is generating the tree with correct branches but the text is not appearing.I am using my json like this:

```
{
"name":"sourcetable",
"children":[{"name":"MARD"},{"name":"MARD"},{"name":"MARD"},{"name":"MARD"}]
}
```

It comes something like this:

[image: No name]

Let me know how i can show the name labels on the collapsible tree.

Comment: as i see the object would be like this text: { name: "Parent node" },

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a bit:

```
nodeStructure: {
        text: { name: "Parent node" },
        children: [
            {
                text: { name: "First child" }
            },
            {
                text: { name: "Second child" }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Taken from here:
http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/

Answer (score -1):

```
var simple_chart_config = {
    chart: {
        container: "#OrganiseChart-simple"
    },
    
    nodeStructure: {
        text: { name: "Parent node" },
        children: [
            {
                text: { name: "First child" }
            },
            {
                [enter image description here][1]text: { name: "Second child" }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Demo Link:
https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/super-simple

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).